# The parameter 'abc' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

### @required to a property gave such ERROR:
The parameter 'lng' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (Documentation)

but removing @, removes the error. how ?
I mean, the value still can be null. What does it have to do with "@" symbol.

see pictures:
[image]

Comment: Can you include as code-snipppet & dart,flutter version

Comment: the @ means the word next to it is a notation, and I think you cannot use there. 
About the null warning, the compiler is basically saying that you defined an atributte as non nullable and you are not initializing it in the constructor. or you define lng as nullable and remove the required keyword or you can define it as non nullable and use the required keyword at the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `@` anymore, just use `required`.

```dart
({ 
  required this.lat,
  required this.lng,
})
```

if you like to accept null data, use `DataType? varName`.

```dart
String? lat;
String? lng;
```

More about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)